# What is the point of the xorg package in Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, gnome, xorg, ubuntu-10.10

I am about to do a minimal installation of Ubuntu 10.10. First, I'll do a command-line install with the minimal Ubuntu cd. Second, I want to install a minimal version of gnome. So I am simply looking to do a `sudo apt-get -y install gnome-core xdm`. On some websites people add in the `xorg` package as well. What is the point of that package, and do I need it for a *minimal* gnome install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*XDM* is the display manager for X Windows, *Xorg* is the X Windows server, both are required (or a suitable alternative). I assume that the reason some people do not mention Xorg is because it is automatically installed alongside another package (would have thought gnome-core has it as a dependency).

Comment: XDM is _not_ required to use X Windows.

Comment: That's not what I meant -- I meant it was required for his particular use (afaik, gdm is not installed with `gnome-core`)

Answer (score 2):

`xorg` contains the Xorg X server. It isn't required for operation of GNOME applications since X is a network-transparent protocol and the actual X server could be running on another machine. Adding it to the install command ensures that a X server is available on the *local* machine.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to manually specify it. If minimal gnome depends on the xorg package, then it will be installed automatically.